# Pausing the training of a neural network - is it possible?

Tags: tensorflow, time, deep-learning, neural-network, training-data

I am training a neural network and the new datasets I am training it on are really big in comparison to the ones used before. Since I am also saving the time it takes to end the training, I cannot use my computer for anything else while it is running since it would alter this measure (CPU would be used for something else and it would take more time). On the other hand, I need to work on other stuff and I can't just leave my pc for days. So, I was thinking of finding a way of being able to pause the training whenever I need to use my pc, to then resume it whenever I want. Is that possible somehow (I am also using hyperopt to optimize hyperparameters)?

Comment: You can save the checkpoints using a callback, after each epoch or iteration. And whenever you stop the model, in the next restart load weights from the last checkpoint. For example, built-in model checkpoint callback [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint) or a custom callback.

Answer (score 0):

It is, but what are you using as tech, tensorflow ?

Normally the trained network return a file when paused or when it has finished his sets that can be reused as a starter.

For exemple the network unet can read a hdf5 file:

```py
save = /Tensorflow/data/history/dernier/unet_ac_9857.hdf5'

if PRE_TRAINED:
    model = unet(save)
else:
    model = unet()
```

you can also add checkpoints:

```py
model_checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(save, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
model.fit(train_dataset, steps_per_epoch=TRAIN_LENGTH // BATCH_SIZE, epochs=50, callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
```

Comment: Yes I am using tensorflow. At the end of the training I save the model obtained in a file, is that what you mean?

Comment: exactly, and you can give it back as a starter

Comment: i edited my post to add an exemple (it's been a while since i worked with that)